# Find groups where a certain condition applies to every value in it

Tags: python, pandas

```
grouped=exp.groupby(["country","year"])["value"].sum().reset_index().sort_values(["country","year"])
grouped["prev_year"]=grouped.groupby("country")["value"].apply(lambda x:x.shift(1))
grouped["increase_vs_prev_year"]=((100*grouped.value-grouped.prev_year)/grouped.prev_year-100).round(1)
grouped
```

Here is the output for the code:
[image]

---

I want to find countries where increase_vs_prev_year was more than 0 in every year

Comment: Can you include the input dataset that can be used to re-produce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need countries with greater like `0` per all values (year)s comapre values for greater by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and then aggregate [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html), last filter indices for countries:

```
s = grouped["increase_vs_prev_year"].gt(0).groupby(grouped["country"]).all()

out = s.index[s].tolist()
```